# Downforce of a F1 car?

Tags: aerodynamics

According to Wikipedia a Formula 1 car produces downforce equal to it's weight at around 130kmh. At 190kmh it produces twice as much downforce.

To my understanding of Physics double the air velocity means 4x more force. It should produce 4x the amount of downforce at 260kmh compared to 130kmh, and 8x the amount at 380kmh. How does the car not fall apart with such forces up to 5 tons acting upon it?

Comment: This is a question about the strength of F1 cars, which is an engineering issue, not physics.

Comment: I think that your 4x comment relates to drag force. Not sure if it also holds for the lift force of a wing or airfoil. Also, not sure if those airfoils on race cars are fixed or have an adjustable angle of attack that can be instantly changed depending on speed and race conditions.

Comment: Why the downvote? In any case what’s your argument for 4x force? It should be clear that the answer must depend on the form of the spoilers winglets ecc.

Comment: Those top speeds are achieved on courses where speed is the ultimate goal. The cars wings are reconfigured for each course, with less downforce on courses where straight-line speed is the key factor, more downforce where cornering  speed is the key factor. On those courses where cornering is key, the stresses and strains due to cornering are of greater concern than the are the vertical loads as the coefficient of friction on those cars is well over unity. Those cars can have a lateral acceleration of six to eight gees. It's the drivers who are the weakest component in the vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that lift and drag both vary with $V^2$. I assume F1 cars are built very strong to take high g-loads, just as [*aerobatic aircraft*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukhoi_Su-26) are.